# Spark Streaming: Increase in Network Activity & CPU load on Driver

Tags: performance, apache-spark, spark-streaming, ganglia

My `Spark Streaming` application has a cycle of 5 minutes. Since past 2 months, there is recurrent pattern seen on the `Driver Node`. Presenting below snapshot of the `performance metrics` as seen from `ganglia`. The same behavior is seen in past weeks too.

1. Setup        : A `driver` with two `executors` (8G, 10 cores) on `EMR`
2. Spark Version: 1.5.2
3. GC           : `CMS` for both driver & executor

**Important**: The application was **started on Saturday** as shown in the charts.

**RAM**
[image]

**CPU**
[image]

**Network**
[image]

Can there be any explanation to this behavior? If I need to investigate, what observational pointers can I derive from this snapshot?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: the code base is actually quite huge. Briefly put, it involves consuming two kafka topics. There are two 'moving-window' Queues (java-objects) maintained on the driver which are fed with the events got from the topics. After that, the two queues are parallelized to get two RDDs and a scoring algorithm is run